# Why keeps Oracle writing into WARNING_SETTINGS$?

Tags: oracle

For tests we have Oracle 11 instance running on a RAM disc. Since the RAM disc is limited in size the database must not do any auditing or anything that keeps increasing the size of anything.

We managed to fix many such leaks but have one left which we don't know how to handle:

The database tries to write to the table

```
WARNING_SETTINGS$
```

resulting (after a couple of weeks) in a

```
ORA-01653: unable to extend table SYS.WARNING_SETTINGS$ by 8 in tablespace SYSTEM
```

while trying to create a database object (a trigger right now)

We tried to disable all writes to that table with this statement

```
begin
  dbms_warning.add_warning_setting_cat('ALL', 'DISABLE', 'SYSTEM');
end;
/
commit;
```

The questions are:

What is the purpose of that table?

Why does Oracle keep writing into it?

How do we make Oracle stop doing that?

Comment: Why the close vote?

Comment: According to http://psoug.org/reference/dbms_warn_int.html it appears to be related to the PL/SQL compiler warnings. What if you run: `ALTER SESSION SET PLSQL_WARNINGS='DISABLE:ALL';` whenever you compile anything? Not sure if this would be equivalent to your `add_warning_setting_cat` or not.

Comment: We rebuild the database and I applied an ALTER SYSTEM SET PLSQL_WARNINGS='DISABLE:ALL'. I'll try to find if this does anything tomorrow.

Comment: This may be applicable: Bug 11720698 : SYS.WARNING_SETTINGS$ NOT CLEANED UP WHEN OBJECT IS DROPPED.

Comment: @LeighRiffel Thanx that seems to be the problem. Wanna make an answer out of the comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bug 11720698 with the title "SYS.WARNING_SETTINGS$ NOT CLEANED UP WHEN OBJECT IS DROPPED." may be causing this.

Comment: This seems to be the reason for our problems. In the bug report they provide a workaround by deleting unused records from the table.

Answer (score 4):

Oracle inserts into `warning_settings$` when you compile an object that produces a compilation warning.

I traced an object creation with (`ALTER SESSION SET PLSQL_WARNINGS='ENABLE:ALL'`) & without (`ALTER SESSION SET PLSQL_WARNINGS='DISABLE:ALL'`) warnings enabled to show this.

With warnings set, we can see the following SQL in the trace file:

```
PARSING IN CURSOR #5 len=94 dep=1 uid=0 oct=2 lid=0 tim=1334927684277374 hv=2385338619 ad='d891dc48' sqlid='fdvfrjy72us7v'
insert into warning_settings$(obj#, warning_num, global_mod, property) values (:1, :2, :3, :4)
END OF STMT
PARSE #5:c=0,e=250,p=0,cr=0,cu=0,mis=1,r=0,dep=1,og=4,plh=0,tim=1334927684277373
```

Interestingly, `ALTER SESSION SET PLSQL_WARNINGS='DISABLE:ALL'` only seems to suppress the output of the warnings to SQL Plus. A trace still shows the table being populated by Oracle:

```
oracle@ironforge:/u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/phill11g2/PHILL11G2/trace$ tail -f PHILL11G2_ora_26759_PHIL_DBA.trc | grep -i warning
ALTER SESSION SET PLSQL_WARNINGS='DISABLE:ALL'
delete from warning_settings$ where obj# = :1
STAT #6 id=1 cnt=0 pid=0 pos=1 obj=0 op='DELETE  WARNING_SETTINGS$ (cr=2 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us)'
STAT #6 id=2 cnt=1 pid=1 pos=1 obj=254 op='INDEX RANGE SCAN I_WARNING_SETTINGS (cr=2 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=1 size=5 card=1)'
insert into warning_settings$(obj#, warning_num, global_mod, property) values (:1, :2, :3, :4)
```

Test PL/SQL snippet used for this & the warning it generated:

```
PHIL@PHILL11G2 > ALTER SESSION SET sql_trace = true;

Session altered.

PHIL@PHILL11G2 > ALTER SESSION SET tracefile_identifier = PHIL_DBA;

Session altered.

PHIL@PHILL11G2 >
PHIL@PHILL11G2 > ALTER SESSION SET PLSQL_WARNINGS='ENABLE:ALL';

Session altered.

PHIL@PHILL11G2 > CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE phil_1
  2  IS
  3  BEGIN
  4    NULL;
  5  END;
  6  /

SP2-0804: Procedure created with compilation warnings

PHIL@PHILL11G2 >
PHIL@PHILL11G2 > show errors;
Errors for PROCEDURE PHIL_1:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
1/1  PLW-05018: unit PHIL_1 omitted optional AUTHID clause; default
     value DEFINER used

PHIL@PHILL11G2 >
```

Answer (score 1):

I can only find a reference to this in Oracle's TimesTen in-memory database docs, but it's clearly there in our 11.1 "plain" database.  See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e21644/systemtables.htm#sthref44).  It's listed as a PL/SQL system table, and there's a comment about "don't query this directly - use the PL/SQL system views instead".

Hmmm... Perhaps it contains foul, forbidden secrets, the kind which have been known to drive men mad.  But...shall we turn our eyes from this knowledge?  Are we not men?!?

(*tap-tap-tap-tap*)

Eyyaaaaaah!  Cthulhu!!  Cthulhu fthagn!!!

*#&^$*#&$^#*&NO CARRIER

Comment: Don't you know the SO motto is "We hate fun"?

Comment: @APC: say it long and say it loud - we're funny, and it's not just looks! (OK, needs work...)

Comment: I'm *somewhat* disappointed nobody caught the Mark Motherspaugh reference.  <*sigh*>  WE ARE DEVO!  WE ARE DEVO!!  WE ARE DEVO!!!